# Algolia - how to set anchor in facets

Tags: algolia

I've just implemented search functionality on my site using Algolia instantsearch.js library.

It automatically generates the facets based on result, then the facets work just like filters to search further in the result. I've included Topics related to the products in the facets and what I want is if someone clicks on the topic then instead of filtering the result further it should take to that particular page.

Can someone please tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 1):

Hi Rajnijant we created the relevant issue in our github because this is currently not possible to do what you want to do: https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/791